# select HealthKit HKActivitySummary -> "NSInvalidArgumentException", "startDateComponents: Date components require a calendar."

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I try to select HealthKit activitySummaries (new with iOS 9.3)

```
@available(iOS 9.3, watchOS 2.2, *)
func selectTodayActivitySummary (store: HKHealthStore, completion: ((summaryQuery: HKActivitySummaryQuery, summary: [HKActivitySummary]?, error: NSError?) -> Void)) {
    guard let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian) else {
        fatalError("*** This should never fail. ***")
    }

    let endDate = NSDate()

    guard let startDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -7, toDate: endDate, options: []) else {
        fatalError("*** unable to calculate the start date ***")
    }

    let units: NSCalendarUnit = [.Day, .Month, .Year, .Era]

    let startDateComponents = calendar.components(units, fromDate: startDate)
    let endDateComponents = calendar.components(units, fromDate:endDate)


    // Create the predicate for the query
    let summariesWithinRange = HKQuery.predicateForActivitySummariesBetweenStartDateComponents(startDateComponents, endDateComponents: endDateComponents)
    //let summariesAtDate = HKQuery.predicateForActivitySummaryWithDateComponents(startDateComponents)

    let query = HKActivitySummaryQuery(predicate: summariesWithinRange) {
        (summaryQuery: HKActivitySummaryQuery, summary: [HKActivitySummary]?, error: NSError?) in

        completion(summaryQuery: summaryQuery, summary: summary, error: error)
    }

    store.executeQuery(query)
}
```

When I run this code as a unit test, I get an exception 
"NSInvalidArgumentException", "startDateComponents: Date components require a calendar."

What is wrong with this code?
This code is almost completely from https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKActivitySummaryQuery_Class/index.html

Tested with XCode 7.3 beta 4 (7D152p), iPhone 6s Plus 9.3 simulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `calendar` property needs to be non-nil on `startDateComponents` and `endDateComponents` (otherwise it is ambiguous which calendar you expect the components to be interpreted in). Unfortunately, `NSCalendar` does not populate that property itself when you call `components(_, fromDate:)` so you'll need to do so manually like this:

```
let startDateComponents = calendar.components(units, fromDate: startDate)
startDateComponents.calendar = calendar
let endDateComponents = calendar.components(units, fromDate:endDate)
endDateComponents.calendar = calendar
```

Comment: Perfect. I'll file a bug report because the code is from Apples documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the question itself. You need to have `.calendar` as one of units as below -

```
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .calendar], from: date)
```

Then you can use these components to retrieve summary as below -

```
    // Create the descriptor.
    let activeSummaryDescriptor = HKActivitySummaryQueryDescriptor(predicate: HKQuery.predicateForActivitySummary(with: components))

    // Run the query.
    let activitySummary = try await activeSummaryDescriptor.result(for: healthStore)
```